# How to open an application in background using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a task at work and I will have to perform certain operations in an application. Since I am automating the stuff, I don't want the application to be visible to the user as I'll perform my operations in the background. I am controlling the application using keyboard commands.

`

```
Private Sub DPS_Click()
Dim x As Variant

Dim Path As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
Path = "C:\xyz\xyz.exe"
x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
Application.SendKeys ("%as")
Application.SendKeys (....)
Application.SendKeys (.....)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With`
```

But the application is still visible to the user and the operations are not done in the background. Any Inputs are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.appwinstyle(v=vs.90).aspx  you are using send keys in the application, so Excel, you need to get the object and then use it's send keys

Comment: Which application are you trying to control / automate? It is hard to suggest anything without knowing the app. Maybe the app cannot be hidden? Maybe there is a simple switch you need to pass to the `Shell` to make it start / run in hidden mode? Maybe there is even a DLL available you can reference in the VBE for direct access to the app. Then you won't have to use `SendKeys` anymore.

Comment: Hi Ralph, I am using an application called DPS which is given by clients and doesn't have any reference. I don't have permission to make any modifications to the application as well.